# cordova contact plugins - emails null

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using "Cordova" to create application for IOS and Android.
And i need to accessed the contacts of the device. I use for that the plugin "org.apache.cordova.contacts".

Here are the part of the code i use to do that, and i get a response...

```
function ContactsCtrl($scope){
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.multiple = true;
    options.filter = "Benoit";
    var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname "];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        for(x in contacts[i]){
            ret += x+' :'+contacts[i][x]+"\n";
        }
    }
    $('#resultContact').html(html);
}
```

And the response :

```
rawId :null
displayName :Nasher
name :[object Object]
nickname :null
phoneNumbers :null
emails :null
...
...
```

The problem :
"emails" field and "phoneNumbers" field are always empty (on android and on iOs) however they exist in the "contacts book"

Anybody have a idee why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find) say:

> contactFields: Contact fields to use as a search qualifier. **The
>   resulting Contact object only features values for these fields.**
>   (DOMString[]) [Required]

You don't add the `emails` and `phoneNumbers` field to your `fields` array. Try:

```
var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname", "emails", "phoneNumbers"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this topic since in my case the contact.displayName was showing up as null (I had displayName in contactFields).

After adding the "name" to contactFields array, the displayName got populated.